# How to save a matrix in C++ in a non-linear way

Tags: performance, caching, matrix, optimization, memory-access

I have to program an optimized multi-thread implementation of the Levenshtein distance problem. It can be computed using dynamic programming with a matrix, the [wikipedia page on Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) covers that well enough.

Now, I can compute diagonal elements concurrently. That is all alright.

My problem now comes with caches. Matrices in c++ are normaly saved in memory row by row, correct? Well, that is not good for me as I need 2 element of the previous row and 1 element of the current row to compute my result, that is horrible cache-wise. The cache will hold the current row (or part of it), then I ask for the previous one which it will probably not hold anymore.
Then for another one, I need a different part of the diagonal, so yet again, I ask for completely different rows and the cache will not have those ready for me.

Therefore, I would like to save my matrix to memory in blocks or maybe diagoals. That will result in fewer cachce misses and make my implementation faster again.

How do you do that? I tried searching the internet, but I could never find anything that would show me the way. Is it possible to tell c++ how to order that type in memory?

EDIT: As some of you seem confused about the nature of my question. I want to save a matrix (does not matter if I will make it a 2D array or any other way) in a custom way into the MEMORY. Normally, a 2D array will save row after row, I need to work with diagonals therefore caches will miss a lot on the huge matrices I will work at (possibly millions of rows and columns).

Comment: "Matrices" are technically not a concept in C++. A straightforward way of creating a matrix data structure is as you say: Storing a vector of rows, each row being a vector of matrix elements. But you can of course implement anything you like instead. Also, you should be aware that, while caches are not always large, they can hold (significantly) more than one cache line at once. Operating on two cache lines at the same time is absolutely no problem.

Comment: do you really need to store you data as matrix? store only elements you require for your calculations in whatever way suites better for you

Comment: "I need 2 element of the previous row and 1 element of the current row to compute my result, that is horrible cache-wise". This access pattern is not horrible cache-wise. Actually, it is very cache-friendly.

Comment: What is the size of your problem ?

Comment: storing the matrix diagonal-wise wouldn't help your problem since there will still be one element on a separate diagonal from the other two

Comment: If you're not fine with this linear order, you might want to check out Morton interleave (this method usually used in HW. Address it makes is bits of x and y interleaved, instead of y*width+x). But I'm not sure that it will gain you anything, as address calculation is not fast. Or maybe you just need to tile the matrix, that's the usual SW solution (put same-sized rectangular parts (a.k.a. tiles) linearly. Then put tiles linearly).

Comment: This question is not really about C++ or any particular language. See also @MaxLanghof's comment.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice, but please just answer my questions... I have considered all possibilities of iterations carefully and for my needs, forcing it to be saved by diagonals or by tiles is actually much better than the linear way C++ would usually save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary comment: "Levenshtein distance" is edit distance (under the common definition). This is a very common problem; you probably don't even need to bother writing a solution yourself. Look for existing code.

Now, finally, for a proper answer... You don't actually need have a matrix at all, and you certainly don't need to "save" it: It's enough to keep merely a "front" of your dynamic programming matrix rather than the whole thing.

But what "front" shall you choose, and how do you advance it? I suggest you use anti-diagonals as your front, and given each anti-diagonal, compute concurrently the next anti-diagonal. Thus it'll be {(0,0)}, then {(0,1),(1,0)}, then {(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)} and so on. Each anti-diagonal requires at most two earlier anti-diagonals - and if we keep the values of each anti-diagonal consecutively in memory, then the access pattern going up the next anti-diagonal is a linear progression along the previous anti-diagonals - which is great for the cache (see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377860/1593077)).

So, you'll "concurrentize" the computation give each thread a bunch of consecutive anti-diagonal elements to compute; that should do the trick. And at any time you will only keep 3 anti-diagonal in memory: the one you're working on and the two previous ones. You can cycle between three such buffers so you don't re-allocate memory all the time (but then make sure to pre-allocate buffers with the maximum anti-diagonal length).

This whole thing should work basically the same for the non-square case.

Comment: Thank you! While it was not exactly what I was looking for (I still do not know how to tell c++ to save a matrix in a different way) it solves the problem in another way in an elegant manner. 

I would like to give you extra points for actually reading the problem I need it for, but I have no way of doing that.

Comment: @JanKolombo: I (and others) were initially thrown off by the phrasing of your title. Also, you can give me one point on this answer by upvoting :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe you may have a mis-perception of (CPU) cache.

It's true that CPU caching is linear - that is, if you access an address in memory, it will bring into the cache some previous and some successive memory locations - which is like "guessing" that subsequent accesses will involve 1-dimensional-close elements. However, this is true on the micro-level. A CPU's cache is made up of a large number of small "lines" (64 Bytes on all cache levels in recent Intel CPUs). The locality is limited to the line; different cache lines can come from completely different places in memory.

Thus, if you "need two elements of the previous row and one element of the current row" of your matrix, then the cache should work very well for you: Some of the cache will hold elements of the previous row, and some will hold elements of the current row. And when you advance to the next element, the cache overall will usually contain the matrix elements you need to access. Just make sure your order of iteration agrees with the order of progression within the cache line.

Also, in some cases you could be faced with a situation where different threads are thrashing the same cache lines due to the mapping from main memory into the cache. Without getting into details, that *is* something you need to think about (but again, has nothing to do with 2D vs 1D data).

**Edit:** As geza notes, if your matrix' lines are long, you will still be reading each memory location twice with the straightforward approach: Once as the current-line, then again as the previous-line, since each value will be evicted from the cache before it's used as a previous-line value. If you want to avoid this, you can iterate over **tiles** of your matrix, whose size (length x width x sizeof(element)) fits into the L1 cache (along with whatever else needs to be there). You can also consider *storing* your data in tiles, but I don't think that would be too useful.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, however, this does not answer my question at all. 

I cannot iterate over tiles as that is not how the algorithm can work and provide results that I need, I need to go iterate through diagonals of the matrix (as only elements on a diagonal are independent of each other) and I need to optimize the caches for iteration over a diagonal. 

Therefore, I want to know if its possible in c++ to save a type into memory differently than it would automaticaly and to force it to structure the data in a certain way.

Comment: @JanKolombo: Wait, are we talking about the dynamic programming "matrix" rather than a proper matrix? ... in that case, I'll write a completely different answer!

Comment: Yes, as I specified in my answer, I am computing the Levenshtein distance, the best method for me (as my solution has to use paralelism for computing this distance on very long strings) is to use a matrix and iterate through diagonals, where every diagonal is computed with the data from the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure, but i think a matrix is stored as a long array one row after the other and is mapped with pointer arithmetic to a matrix, so you always refer to the same address and calculate the distance in the memory where your value is located

Otherwise you can implement it easily as this type and implement operator[int, int] for your matrix

Comment: This is only one way of storing a matrix, namely the one in the question (more or less), and the question author already covered why they think it is suboptimal. You would either have to explain why their assumptions are wrong or show a _different_ storage format that does not have these concerns.